# Cómo pasar correctamente el valor de un input a otro componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

estoy practicando con formik e hice un formulario multistep
todo bien con los inputs, pero a la hora de crear un input autoincrementable a través de botones, esos valores no se pasan al resumen final, pero sí pasan si le pongo por ejemplo en el input un valor de 100,

entonces, me gustaría saber en qué estoy fallando?

les dejo el código
https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-http-w8t4c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: El codigo debes ponerlo en tu pregunta, editala y agregalo.

Comment: @DragonDEV, agrega algo de código, por lo menos el componente formSecondStep, para que no cierren la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Antes que todo echa un vistazo a [cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), cito:

> Si es posible crear un ejemplo vivo del problema al que puedas enlazar (por ejemplo, en http://sqlfiddle.com/ o http://jsbin.com/) entonces hazlo - pero también incluye el mismo código en tu pregunta. No todos pueden acceder a sitios externos, y los enlaces se pueden quebrar con el tiempo.

Por favor edita tu pregunta de manera en la que incluya el código que presenta problemas, contribuye a la comunidad así como yo estoy contribuyendo con tu problema.

El problema que tienes está en la línea 6 de `FormSecondStep.jsx`:

```
const [countMetro1, setCountMetro1] = useState(countMetro1)
```

No puedes inicializar a través de `useState` el estado con la misma variable que estas definiendo... Utiliza por ejemplo el valor de cero. Así:

```
const [countMetro1, setCountMetro1] = useState(0)
```